# How do I read the name of a text file as a String in Python?

Tags: python, function, text-files

I have a text file named doc123.txt, I want to create files named sub_doc123.txt. The file doc_123.txt is an input for a function.

Edit: Sorry if this is basic and I am unable to see the quick solution. Essentially:

```
def test(main_txt_file):
    print main_txt_file

test(practice_split_3.txt)
```

This does not work as it says "NameError: name 'practice_split_3' is not defined".

Comment: You are asking how to concatenate two strings which is a very basic task. You should read a basic tutorial http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/

Comment: I understand how to concatenate two strings. My question is how to get that string name from the text file.

Comment: @Shivani, that is irrelevant, you have showed no attempt and it is still something pretty basic that with a small bit of research you could figure out, your question basically says I have this homework and need someone to do it for me.

Comment: Your edit now does not even  use a string for the filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need a function for this. Following code will do.

```
inp = raw_input("Enter name of doc")
outName = 'sub_' + inp
```

Comment: Probably because you should not be encouraging questions of such poor quality.

Comment: This does not mean that we stop helping those in need.

Comment: I don't think doing someones homework for them is really helping someone in need

Comment: I think my question is unclear. I am just wondering how to get the file name from an inputted text file. I understand how to manipulate it from there. Sorry, not trying to take the easy way out. I am a beginner in Python.

Comment: Try putting it within double quotes `test("practice_split_3.txt")`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `os` module as you are wanting to manipulate (read/write) files in the directory. It would be additionally beneficial that you save the file used to manipulate your text files in the same directory as the files you would like to manipulate.

```
import os
for fileName in os.listdir("."):
        os.rename(fileName, fileName.replace("doc123.txt", "sub_doc123.txt"))
```